# Is induction really required to prove this?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> **Given:**  $2^{n-1}$  subsets of a set with  $n$  elements with the property that any three have nonempty intersection, prove that the
> intersection of all the sets is nonempty.
>
> **My Solution:**  Let $S$ be the family of subsets of the set  $A$  with  $n$  elements. Because  $S$  has $2^{n-1}$  elements, for every
> subset B of A, either B or its complement  $B^c$ is in  $S$.  $WLOG$,
> let's assume that subset  $B$  is in  $S$, this implies that its
> complement  $B^c$  will be in  complement of  $S$  (which is  $S^c$).
> This will follow for every element in  $S$. So now it directly follows
> that intersection of all the subsets will be an empty subset.  $QED$
>
> **Putnam and Beyond:** Let $S$  =  {$A_1, A_2, . . . ,$
> $A_{2^{n−1}}$}  be the family of subsets of the set  $A$  with  $n$
> elements. Because  $S$  has $2^{n−1}$  elements, for any subset $B$
> of  $A$, either  $B$  or its complement  $B^c$  is in  $S$. (They
> cannot both be in  $S$  by the other hypothesis.) So if $A_i$  and
> $A_j$  are in  $S$, then either ${A_i}∩{A_j}$  is in  $S$, or its
> complement is in  $S$. If the complement is in  $S$  then
> ${A_i}∩{A_j}∩({A_i}∩{A_j})^{c}$  is empty, contradicting the fact that
> the intersection of any three elements of  $S$  is nonempty. Hence
> ${A_i}∩{A_j}∈S$.  We will now show by induction on  $k$  that the
> intersection of any  $k$  sets in  $S$  is nontrivial. We just proved
> the base case  $k=2$. Assume that the property is true for any  $k−1$
> elements of $S$, and let us prove it for $A_{i1}, A_{i2}, . . .
> > ,A_{ik}∈S$. By the induction hypothesis, $A_{i1}∩···∩Ai_{k−1}∈S$, and
> also $A_{ik}∈S$, so $(A_{i1}∩···∩A_{ik−1})∩A_{ik}$  is in $S$. This
> completes the induction. For  $k=2n−1$, we obtain that the
> intersection of all sets in  $S$  is nontrivial.

As it may be seen my solution is fully inspired by that of book but I really couldn't get it and feel that induction is unnecessary in this. Is there some logical error in what I wrote up or not?

Comment: "So now it directly follows that the intersection of all the subsets will be an empty subset." How does this directly follow?

Comment: A good indication something is not right is that you don't use the condition that "any three have nonempty intersection".

Comment: @K.Jiang it is so because complement of every subset in S lies in say another set S' then S U S' will now have 2^n elements and it is known that intersection of subset with its complement is a null set. Let A_1, A_2...A_2^{n-1} have complements {A-1}' and so on their pairwise intersection will be null. therefore intesection off all subsets of A will be a null set.

Comment: Well of course the intersection of *all* subsets of $A$ is empty, but we are not interested in the intersection of *all* subsets, just that of $A_1, ..., A_{2^{n - 1}}$, right? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You seem to be concluding the exact opposite of what you are supposed to prove, and I do not see how your conclusion follows. We can easily construct a family such that for every $B\subseteq A$, either $B$ or $B^c$ lies in the family, but not both, but where the intersection of all elements of $S$ is empty. So I do not see how your claim, or its negation, would follow from the properties you have enunciated in your argument.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood the question. You are not asked to show the intersection of all subsets of $A$ is empty (that is *trivial*!) You are asked to show that if $S$ has the given properties, then the intersection of all subsets of $A$ **that are elements of $S$** is **nonempty**.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sorry bro, I misunderstood the question, now I get it. Thank You so much..

Comment: @K.Jiang I got the question now, thank you